# sql database name in textbox ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

i need just to print the database name in text box using asp.net and i have the .aspx code like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.   Visit the faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see details of how this site is run.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on how to use the [sqlDatasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select.aspx)  it has an example with a sqldatasource and a label.

Other ways to get the database name would be to search your database connection string for initial catalogue or something.  You could also use the name of the database as the connection string name.  then you could do something like

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>

TextBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

very bad idea. bad security.
if u really need to do it, atleast do it with DropDownList. a bit better but still security problem

Answer (score -1):

```
 //       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ></asp:TextBox>
  //          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
  //         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
   //        SelectCommand="SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName">
```

this is the code

Comment: Is this really the answer?  Or did you mean to put this in your question?

Comment: @forono2: you should delete this answer.